# How to resolve TS error Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am beginner of TypeScript. In during coding, I got an error Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ts but I dont know how to solve it. Can someone help me fix this?

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface ImageProps {
    src: string;
    alt?: string;
    className?: string;
    fallback?: string;
}

interface FallbackImage {
    noImage?: string;
}

export const Image = (props: ImageProps, ref: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLImageElement>): React.ReactElement => {
    const { src, alt, className, fallback, ...otherProps } = props;    
    const [errFallback, setErrFallback] = React.useState<string>('');
    const fallbackImg: FallbackImage = {
        noImage: '',
    };

    const errFallbackHandler = () => {
        setErrFallback(fallbackImg[fallback]);
    };

    return (
        <img
            ref={ref}
            alt={alt || ''}
            className={className}
            src={src || errFallback}
            {...otherProps}
            onError={errFallbackHandler}
        />
    );
};

export default React.forwardRef(Image);
```

Image for this error:

[image]

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: @GuyIncognito  sorry for my omission, i have updated the image of this error

Comment: please dont vote down my question :(

Comment: You've defined `fallback` as an optional prop so you have to decide what you want to happen when it's undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. This error says, that you can not access `fallback[undefined]`. You can make `fallback` property required or you can provide default value in `const { src, alt, className, fallback = "noImage", ...otherProps } = props;`

Another problem is that `fallbackImg["noImage"]`, `fallbackImg["otherPossibleString"]` can be `undefined` and in state definition you say that state have to be string. You can provide default value in handler `setErrFallback(fallbackImg[fallback] || "")` or extend state type to `React.useState<string | undefined>();`

BTW:
you can use this type of fallback to allow only interface attribute names:

```
interface ImageProps {
    src: string;
    alt?: string;
    className?: string;
    fallback?: keyof FallbackImage;
}
```